# Update membership level via API request if using simple membership plugin

Tags: rest-api, mobile, membership

I plan to use [simple membership plugin](https://simple-membership-plugin.com/) to handle the membership part. But I found no way to update membership level in mobile app via API request. May I know if it has any other ways from render webview with specified wordpress url in my mobile app to achieve this? thanks. So good if there are controller under JSON API settings.

Comment: It would require Simple Membership exposing that functionality via a REST API that you can use, so you're going to need to check with them if their plugin support such a thing. WordPress has its own REST API for accessing its own basic data, but if you need to interact with 3rd-party plugins then they need to support their own API. You need to check this before you waste any time developing something assuming that this exists.

Comment: @JacobPeattie understand, let me check if there are other alternatives then, thanks